# Random Forest (rfsrc package): multivariate analysis

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

I'm trying to evaluate interactions between promotions on child products.
My dataset counts 1073 dicotomic variables (`x`) and 11 dependent (`y`). I'm using `rfsrc` from `randomForestSRC` package in R.

```
fit2=rfsrc(Multivar(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11) ~.,data = data3, importance =TRUE)
err <- get.mv.error(fit2)
err
vmp.std <- get.mv.vimp(fit2, standardize = TRUE)
plot(fit2)
```

Why, by default, R give me back just `y1` as response?

```
                         Sample size: 602
                     Number of trees: 1000
           Forest terminal node size: 5
       Average no. of terminal nodes: 179.484
No. of variables tried at each split: 358
              Total no. of variables: 1073
              Total no. of responses: 11
         User has requested response: y1
       Resampling used to grow trees: swr
    Resample size used to grow trees: 602
                            Analysis: mRF-R
                              Family: regr+
                      Splitting rule: mv.mse *random*
       Number of random split points: 10
                % variance explained: 53.03
                          Error rate: 0.4
```

There are some command to plot some informations?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of [plot.variable.rfsrc.R](https://rdrr.io/cran/randomForestSRC/src/R/plot.variable.rfsrc.R) which is called to plot your randomForestSRC object, the default for `m.target` is `NULL` And it feeds this to another function [get.univariate.target](https://rdrr.io/cran/randomForestSRC/src/R/data.utilities.R) which will take the first variable. If you want to plot other variables, you specify `m.target=...`

```
library(mlr)
library(randomForestSRC)

yeast = getTaskData(yeast.task)
data = yeast[,c(1:3,15:100)]
head(data)
fit = rfsrc(Multivar(label1,label2,label3) ~.,data = data, importance =TRUE)

plot(fit,m.target="label2")
```

[image]

```
plot(fit,m.target="label3")
```

[image]